# Reading string into struct data in C

Tags: c, struct

```
 typedef struct Node {
   char number[5];
    struct Node *next;
 } Node;   


    char userString[5];
    scanf("%s", userString);

    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->number = userString;
```

I'm trying to read a string entered by the user into "number" in the struct Node, but I'm getting an error that says "assignment to expression with array type". What I can do to fix this?

Comment: Use `strcpy()` to copy a string.  Use `%4s` in the format string to prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: I would suggest `strncpy()` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy)

Comment: Oh no, here we go again. Don't let cdlane here you suggest `strncpy()` the padding of the unused space in the array can get costly.

Comment: I would suggest [properly formatting your code](http://prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). But I must say... your post was adequately messy to serve as an example, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

instead of

```
 newNode->number = userString;
```

Use strncpy()

```
 strncpy(newNode->number, userString,sizeof(newNode->number));
```

Reason why strcpy is needed :
newnode->number = userSting , newnode->number is char[] type hence you need to loop and fill all the content byte by byte, while your statement is pointing to the string thats why compiler is giving "assignment to expression with array type"

Now why i have used the strncpy instead of strcpy ...
because strncpy limits the bounds of copying.

I hope you understand.

Comment: Can you explain why I have to use strcpy() instead of the way that I did it?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

you need to use [strcpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) function to correctly copy data from `userString` to your `number` array.